# LINQ queries against Open XML

Tags: linq, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have ID of WorksheetPart object obtained earlier from:

```
var id = document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);
```

Now I'm trying to get object back by using LINQ. However, I'm unable to find ID property of the mentioned object:

```
var worksheetPart = document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.Where(x => x.??? == id).First();
```

What property can I use instead of ??? placeholder?

Comment: is `WorksheetParts` member of `WorksheetPart`? Couldn't find at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.worksheetpart_members.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are not finding ID property WorksheetPart class because it does not exist (see [WorksheetPart Member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.worksheetpart_members.aspx)s).

The following code should give you what you need:

```
var TargetPart = document.WorkbookPart.GetPartByID(id);
```

Note: both **GetPartByID(*id*)** and **GetIdOfPart(*part*)** are members of WorkbookPart class